# Validation of child attributes based on a parent condition in Mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, mongoid, associations, conditional-statements

I am trying to `validate_presence_of` child attributes based on a condition if an attribute in the parent document is true or false. Please take a look at my models below:

```
class Venue
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :name, type: String
  field :has_locations, type: Mongoid::Boolean

  embeds_many :locations
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :locations
end
```

And the child (embedded) model.

```
class Location
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :city

  embedded_in :venue, inverse_of: :locations

  # Here I want to validate presence of :city, but only if
  # :has_locations in Venue is true
  validates_presence_of :city, if: ????

end
```

Then I have a single form with the checkbox for `:has_locations` and `fields_for` for the nested location attributes. My views and controllers are all set up, I think I am just not understanding how to go about this child-parent conditional validation in models. Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

After more tinkering, I was able to achieve the desired functionality like so, not sure if the best approach, but it is what it is, although there's also now a new issue with customizing an error message. My models look like this now:

```
class Venue
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :name, type: String
  field :has_locations, type: Mongoid::Boolean

  embeds_many :locations
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :locations, reject_if: :no_location_required

  private

  def no_location_required
    has_locations == false
  end
end
```

and

```
class Location
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :city

  embedded_in :venue, inverse_of: :locations

  validates_presence_of :city

end
```

Now this seems to work, but the validation error message displayed for some reason is generic: "Locations is invalid". I would expect it to return "City is required". I tried playing around with error messages in `en.yml`, but to no avail as of yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the `validates_associated`. This validates whether the associated object or objects are all valid.

So this goes to your parent model like:

```
class Venue
 include Mongoid::Document

 field :name, type: String
 field :has_locations, type: Mongoid::Boolean

 embeds_many :locations
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :locations

 #validate the associated locations if has_locations is checked (or true)
 validates_associated :locations, if: Proc.new { |venue| venue.has_locations }
end
```

Now, add whatever normal validation you'd like to add in location model:

```
class Location
 include Mongoid::Document

 field :city

 embedded_in :venue, inverse_of: :locations

 # Here I want to validate presence of :city
 validates_presence_of :city
 #Never use validates_associated :venue here if we have already use it in the associated model, otherwise will be a circular dependency and cause infinite recursion.
end
```

Comment: Thanks Manoj! I tried your approach, but it doesn't work, it tries to validate nested attributes regardless of the condition, so checking or unchecking :has_locations has no effect, the validation occurs either way. Hmm...

Comment: Can anyone supply a mongoose representation of the above resolve?